# how to make a plot line default to not visable in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Ok so I have this line of code, and I would like for it not to default to visable, as it is right now sure I can just open it and turn it off in the style menu, but If possible I would like to have it start off that way.
Thanks in advance for taking a look

```
plot(tsl, color=colr, linewidth=3, title="BUY/SELL Chart Line")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter `display`

```
plot(tsl, color=colr, linewidth=3, title="BUY/SELL Chart Line", display=display.none)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show a checkbox in the script settings (cog wheel) to show/hide the line. Default hidden.

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

bool        visible = input(false, "Show BUY/SELL Chart Line")

var float   tsl = 100
var color   colr = color.red

plot(visible ? tsl : na, color=colr, linewidth=3, title="BUY/SELL Chart Line")
```

Comment: I tried the solution you posted and it returned with tsl is already defined. And it is already defined in a line previous to the line I posted.                                                                                                        tsl=iff(avn==1,sup,res)               The line I post plots a line that is either red or green depending on other things, I just thought it would be bad manners to post the whole script due to its length, but maybe I need to?

Comment: My solution doesn't throw any errors on my side. No bad manners at all. Posting the complete script is encouraged, because it helps the community better understand the issue. So yes, please edit your question and post the full script.